# Stopping child activity to return back to parent activity

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-activity

I have an Android activity that is launching a child activity, which runs Sygic navigation on a surfaceview.

Launching the child activity works great, the navigation starts up. However, when they exit out of the Sygic application, I want to close the child activity and return back to showing the parent activity. As you can see, in the Finish() method I've tried calling both this.finish(); and getParent().finish(); however neither are working. All it does is show a black screen, which I'm guessing is the surface view. Any ideas how I can get it to successfully close the child activity and show the parent activity again?

Here is the code to launch the child activity:

```
NavigationActivity.SygicModule = this;
        Log("Creating intent for navigation activity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NavigationActivity.class);
        Log("Starting navigation activity");
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the xml for the child navigation activity view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">
    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"></SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code for the child navigation activity:

```
package ti.sygic;

public class NavigationActivity extends SygicDriveActivity {

    private static final String LCAT = "SygicModule";
    private static SError error = new SError();
    private static Activity currentActivity = null;
    public static SygicModule SygicModule;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        currentActivity = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(TiRHelper.getApplicationResource("layout.sygicmain"));
            final ApiCallback apicallback = new ApiCallback() {
                public void onRunDrive() {
                    try {
                        final SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(TiRHelper.getApplicationResource("id.surfaceView"));

                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                runDrive(surface, getPackageName()); // starts the drive app
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log("Failed to find id.surfaceView!");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } // surface

                }

                public void onInitApi() // gets called after runDrive();
                {
                    // code to make sure that gps is enabled before initializing
                    Log("Checking that gps is enabled");
                    String provider = "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider";
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
                    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
                    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

                    if (!Settings.Secure.isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        Log("Gps is not enabled, showing gps settings");
                        final Intent poke = new Intent();
                        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", provider);
                        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                        sendBroadcast(poke);
                    }

                    int status = ApplicationAPI.InitApi(getPackageName(), true, msgHandler); // api initialization
                    Log("Status = " + Integer.toString(status));

                    if (status != 1) {
                        Log("InitApi failed! " + status);
                    }
                    else {
                        //start checking every second if application is running. if it isn't then finish this and parent activities.
                        //note: we wouldn't have to do this if APP_EXIT event actually fired. :(
                        CheckIfRunning();
                    }
                }
            };

            ApplicationAPI.startDrive(apicallback);

        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e1) {
            Log("Failed to find resource!");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void navigateTo(Float latitude, Float longitude) {
        try
        {
            Log("navigateTo: " + latitude + " / " + longitude);

            Integer lat = (int)(latitude * 100000);
            Integer lon = (int)(longitude * 100000);

            //start navigation.
            Log("Starting navigation for " + lat + " / " + lon);
            SWayPoint wayPoint = new SWayPoint();
            wayPoint.SetLocation(lat, lon);
            ApplicationAPI.StartNavigation(error, wayPoint, 0, true, true, 0);//NavigationParams.NpMessageAvoidTollRoadsUnable
            Log("Start navigation result: " + error.nCode + " " + error.GetDescription());

            //if waiting for gps, call in a bit.
            if(error.nCode == -6)
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                navigateTo(latitude, longitude);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Log(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    final ApplicationHandler msgHandler = new ApplicationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(int nEvent, String strData) {
            Log("Event No. " + Integer.toString(nEvent) + " detected."); // event handling
            switch (nEvent) {
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_APP_EXIT:
                    Log("In EVENT_APP_EXIT event");
                    Finish();
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_WAIPOINT_VISITED:
                    Log("Waypoint visited.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_ROUTE_COMPUTED:
                    Log("Route computed.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_ROUTE_FINISH:
                    Log("Route finished.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_POI_WARNING:
                    Log("Poi warning!.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_CHANGE_LANGUAGE:
                    Log("Language changed.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_EXIT_MENU:
                    Log("Menu exited.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_MAIN_MENU:
                    Log("Entering main menu.");
                    break;
                case ApplicationEvents.EVENT_BORDER_CROSSING:
                    Log("Crossing border.");
            }
        }
    };

    private void CheckIfRunning()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    int numTimesNotRunning = 0;
                    while(true)
                    {
                        boolean isRunning = ApplicationAPI.IsApplicationRunning(error, 0) == 1;
                        if(isRunning)
                        {
                            Log("App is running, will check again in 2 seconds");
                            numTimesNotRunning = 0;
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else {
                            if(numTimesNotRunning < 3)
                            {
                                numTimesNotRunning++;
                                Log("App not running, num times " + numTimesNotRunning);
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                            }
                            else
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    Log("App is not running, calling sygicmodule finish!");
                    Finish();
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    Log(exc.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void Finish()
    {
        Log("In NavigationActivity Finish");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try
                {
                    //launch parent activity.
                    Log("Starting parent activity");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, SygicModule.getActivity().getClass());
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                    //finish current activity.
                    Log("Finishing activity");
                    //setContentView(null);
                    currentActivity.finish();
                }
                catch(Exception exc)
                {
                    Log(exc.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void Log(String message) {
        //org.appcelerator.kroll.common.Log.i(LCAT, message);
        if(message != null && message.length() > 0)
            android.util.Log.i(LCAT, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try starting parent activity from navigation activity when it finish?  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ParentActivity.class);

Comment: The parent activity is already running underneath the child activity, if I started it over top then it'd be running twice which doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @Justin you can pass in the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP when launching the intent to get your currently running Activity and bring it to the front of the stack. More details on how that works here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: @onit are you saying that I should do R4j's suggestion, but with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag? Or are you saying that I should set that flag when launching the child activity?

Comment: @Justin Do R4j's suggestion. Before you launch the intent back to the parent activity, just set that intent for the flag. It should just bring the parent activity to the top of the stack instead of creating a new instance.

Comment: @onit Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work. It says "Trying to launch ti.sygic/.SygicActivity" and then it times out with the error "Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{41d1a088 ti.sygic/.SygicActivity}". It still just shows the black screen through all of this. Any other ideas? The code has been updated.

Comment: @Justin This may not do anything, but try running it without calling currentActivity.finish(). That call should not be necessary, since the CLEAR_TOP flag should be calling finish on the activity anyways. I'm not sure if there is some error from finish being called on the activity twice.

Comment: @onit Unfortunately that didn't have any effect. :( Any idea why it would fail to launch the parent activity?

Comment: @Justin Not sure right now. Maybe if I have more time later I can look over the code more closely.

Comment: @Justin I wonder why you put finish code into a thread, then you call it in another thread?

Comment: @R4j The CheckIfRunning thread is to check every couple seconds if the Sygic navigation is still running or not. This has to be in a separate thread or else it would block the UI. When calling finish, I attempt to close the child activity on the UI thread because that allows it to get a little farther, as it will say "Trying to launch [parent activity]". If I have Finish run on the separate non-UI thread then it doesn't even get this far.

Comment: Just wondering if you made any progress on this?  Currently trying to solve exactly the same problem, but hadn't even got as far as you had -- I'd just noticed that ApplicationEvents.EVENT_APP_EXIT wasn't sent, and was considering the whole CheckIfRunning thread idea when I spotted your question here.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reference the parent activity instead of just calling `finish();`

i.e. `YourActivityClassName.this.finish();`

Would cause your activity to finish, Make sure to add this call on the `DriveEvent.EVENT_APP_EXIT` and your activity should close moments after Sygic has exited